# Send image with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload an image to the server using Retrofit2, but am very unsure on how to do so.

The documentation left me a bit confused and I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39345385/2402271), but it did not work for me.

Here is the code snippet I'm currently using, which doesn't send anything to the server:

```
// Service
@Multipart
@POST("0.1/gallery/{galleryId}/addImage/")
Call<ResponseBody> addImage(@Path("galleryId") String galleryId, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);

//Call
MultipartBody.Part imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));
Call<ResponseBody> call = service. addImage("1234567890", imagePart);
```

However, I'm able to do it just fine using Retrofit 1.9 with a TypedFile.

Am I doing something wrong or Retrofit2 has some issue with this sort of thing?

Comment: Try to use `"multipart/form-data"` instead of `"image/*"`

Comment: Have you tried that solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681750/retrofit-2-0-multipart/37681984#37681984

Comment: May be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078192/send-file-to-server-via-retrofit2-as-object/39108171#39108171

Comment: Were you finally able to do it? Let me know if not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled for a while with this to, I ended up with this solution to finally make it work... Hopes it helps:

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Id",Utils.toRequestBody("0"));
map.put("Name",Utils.toRequestBody("example"));
String types = path.substring((path.length() - 3), (path.length()));

File file = new File(pathOfYourFile);
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file);
map.put("file\"; filename=\"cobalt." + types + "\"", fileBody);

Call<ResponseBody> call = greenServices.upload(map);
```

In the `greenServices` interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST(Constants.URL_UPLOAD)
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> uploadNew(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please check how we can send image in retrofit2.In form of part you need to send image and other data as well.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("0.1/gallery/{galleryId}/addImage/")
    Call<User> checkapi (@Part("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\" ") RequestBody file , @Part("FirstName") RequestBody fname, @Part("Id") RequestBody id);
}

File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), firstNameField.getText().toString());
RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), AZUtils.getUserId(this));
Call<User> call = client.editUser(AZUtils.getToken(this), fbody, name, id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        AZUtils.printObject(response.body());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Thanks hope this will help you.